# Synchronizing markdown automatically in the translated text (ProGit book, sources available)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Summary:** What is the efficient way of wrapping the listed substrings in the translated content to backticks?

**Motivation:** I am synchronizing the *markdown* markup in the translated text with the original. I do have a good translation of the ProGit book by Scott Chacon into Czech. Unfortunately, it was typeset using completely different toolchain than the original, and the original markup has lost. So far, I was successfull to transform majority of the content back to the *markdown* and synchronize the document structure with the original. The next step is to fix using backticks around `code` in the translation.

**The situation**

Say, I have the following paraghraph from the original. Actually, it is a long line without newlines if it matters:

```
    On Windows systems, Git looks for the `.gitconfig` file in the 
    `$HOME` directory (`C:\Documents and Settings\$USER` for most 
    people). It also still looks for /etc/gitconfig, although it’s 
    relative to the MSys root, which is wherever you decide to 
    install Git on your Windows system when you run the installer.
```

I have also the translated paragraph:

```
    Ve Windows používá Git soubor .gitconfig, který je umístěný v 
    domovském adresáři (u většiny uživatelů C:\Documents and 
    Settings\$USER). Dále se pokusí vyhledat ještě soubor 
    /etc/gitconfig, který je relativní vůči kořenovému adresáři. 
    Ten je umístěn tam, kam jste se rozhodli nainstalovat Git po 
    spuštění instalačního programu.
```

Using regular expressions, I do extract the following list from the original (here the `repr()` -- hence the doubled backslashes):

```
    ['.gitconfig', '$HOME', 'C:\\Documents and Settings\\$USER']
```

What is the efficient way of wrapping the listed substrings in the translated content to backticks? The problem also is that some paragraphs may have the same substring repeated several times. I also cannot tell you what other complications can happen. (["My brain hurts, too!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M68GeL8PafE))

**A side note:** For those more interested in the problem, everything is available at https://github.com/pepr/progitCZ (commit 04d1354656276bf1e6ba7305d06c12faca267a19, just now; warning, comments are in Czech). The problem is related to the `util/cz.py` script. It is the fourth pass -- implemented in `pass4.py`. Currently, I convert the list to the set, and then I call `str.replace()` for each of the substrings.

The `info_aux_cs\pass4backticks.txt` file shows comparison of the automated process. The `info_aux_cs\pass4.txt` shows the "fixed" result, the `txtCorrected\RucneUpravovanyVysledekPass2.txt` shows the last manually modified phase.

Another problem is... The structure of the document is already synchronized. On the other hand, the content of the paragraphs (the translation) was not checked yet for newer things in original.

**Update -- new problem observed**

The automatic replacements may be ambiguous. I did observed the case like `['git clone', 'clone', ...]`. As the `set` is created first, the `clone` can be actually wrapped earlier. This way

```
some text git `clone` other text
```

appears where the

```
some text `git clone` other text
```

should be the correct replacement.

I am aware that the approach is very heuristic, and actually need not to be done extremely precisely. Once the automatically replaced text will become the source for manual editing. This way, part of the solution can be visualizing suspicious differences that should be checked by human eye and fixed by human hands :)

Do you have any idea on how to find the most reliable way to solve that problem? Here are some heuristics that came to my mind -- i.e. when to visualize a potential problem:

- All substrings from the original should be found in the translation. Otherwise, translation is somehow specific or not up-to-date, or simply crippled. It can happen that translation can change she substring, but this should be recognized and the check should be explicitly suppressed later.
- The order of substrings may not be preserved in the target language. Anyway, the same number of substrings in the same order is a good sign that the replacement was successfull.
- Should the longest substrings be replaced first?
- ...but the shorter substings would be replaced in the next step?
- Could a regular expression pattern be constructed from the substring and the greediness of regular expression be used to replace backtick-quote all patterns at once?

*Any* good idea is highly welcome ;)

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution using regular expressions be the most promissing, so far. I will be quite happy to accept your better solution if you find one :)

Firstly, here is the regular expression to find the backticked substring:

```
rexBackticked = re.compile(r'`(\S.*?\S?)`')
```

Having the original `enpara` and the translated `cspara` paragraphs, I can extract the lists of backticked substrings like this:

```
enlst = rexBackticked.findall(enpara)
cslst = rexBackticked.findall(cspara)
```

Then I test whether the Czech paragraph should be modified:

```
if set(enlst) != set(cslst) or len(enlst) != len(cslst):
```

If yes, then I create a differential list of substrings that are not but should be backticked in the `cspara` (can possibly be written better):

```
    dlst = enlst[:]   # copy
    for s in cslst:
        if s in dlst:
            dlst.remove(s)
```

Now I need to build a regular expression object for recognizing the `dlst` substrings. I have defined the following function that does that:

```
def buildRex(self, lst):
    '''Build a regular expression mathing substrings from the lst.'''

    # Build a list of escaped unique substrings from the input list.
    # The order is not important now as it must be corrected later.
    lst2 = [re.escape(s) for s in set(lst)]

    # Join the escaped substrings to form the regular expression
    # pattern, build the regular expression, and return it. There could
    # be longer paterns that contain shorter patterns. The longer patterns
    # should be matched first. This way, the lst2 must be reverse sorted
    # by the length of the patterns.
    pat = '|'.join(sorted(lst2, key=len, reverse=True))
    rex = re.compile(pat)
    return rex
```

Now I can use it to replace all non-overlapping substrings in the `cspara`:

```
    rex = self.buildRex(dlst)
    cspara, n = rex.subn(r'`\g<0>`', cspara)
```

Where `n` is the number of replacements that could be important for future checking.

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: Updated: the patterns in the rex builder must be reverse sorted by length.